# Which files should I ignore with Git (.gitignore) for an Xcode 5 project?

Tags: git, xcode5, gitignore

Which files should I include in `.gitignore` when using Git with Xcode 5?

Answer (score 7):

Use this to ignore binary and project files

```
# Created by http://www.gitignore.io

### Objective-C ###
# OS X
.DS_Store

# Xcode
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa

# CocoaPods
Pods


### Xcode ###
build
*.xcodeproj/*
!*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
!*.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
```

Source: http://www.gitignore.io/

Comment: Another good source would be the repository GitHub uses for their default `.gitignore` files: https://github.com/github/gitignore and look for the Objective-C file

Comment: You could make it an answer! I like the `# CocoaPods \n Pods`

Comment: @klaustopher Actually, I think gitignore.io is a proxy for that github project ^^ You can even select many templates (e.g., xcode + objective-c), and gitignore.io will merge them and generate a .gitignore file for you.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this basic setup works well for most projects:

```
.DS_Store
xcuserdata
```